# Erasing or Clearing the Qcolor or Fill in polygon color which is drawn using pythonqt5 in particular area using python

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, opencv3.0

when I click on the particular area which is bounded by the co-ordinates,

the area should be clear the color present on the image and particular area should become transparent and image in that area should be visible

The output I am getting

[image]

Required is :

Required Output is

[image]

can anyone suggest me the way or code in python or python qt5(PyQt5)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I just want to try it if you can help with code it will be help full

Comment: You have to provide *your* code. Without it we cannot help you in any way.